# get ngTemplate innerHtml in directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I need to show the ng-template content on hover similar to [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#overview)

The basic demo version is created on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4bgpf5)

Toggle popover-content display property, shows the element (means, it is rendered)

```
.popover-content {
  /* display: none; */
```

But it renders outside the element.

Is there a way that a parent wrapping element be added to it or how to extract the html of popover content, so a new div element can be created and appended.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to do some nasty changes like touching the `innerHTML` instead use the almightly css adjacent selector `~` it will hide show the adjacent element, only catch is, that the parent element of the element containing the directive should be wrapped in a span with `position: relative` by doing this you can style the adjacent inserted element with `position: absolute` and achieve the desired effect!

styles.css

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
.popover {
  position: relative;
}
.popover-content {
  display: none;
}

.popover:hover ~ .popover-content {
  display: block;
}
```

popover.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPopover]'
})
export class PopoverDirective {
  el;
  @Input() template!:TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor(el:ElementRef,private vcf:ViewContainerRef) {
     this.el  = el;
     el.nativeElement.classList.add('popover');

   }

   ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.vcf.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
   }

}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnq1cf)

Comment: Thanks. Thats a good solution. But I am using tippyjs (not mentioned in question) that takes care of the css part. I need to parse the html and pass it to tippy instance... So my target is to parse the html. Thats it.